# How can we calculate the area covered by the trees in google earth pic or even just a ratio of Trees to other things

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Is there any efficient way by which we can we calculate the area covered by trees using machine learning in any google earth image. We can re-train our data using tensorflow and inception trained dataset to identify whether there is tree or not, but I can't think of any way to find out how many trees or how kuch area it is covering. Is there anything we can do.
I use Python, Tensorflow for machine learning. 
P.s : don't know much about machine learning but can work with steps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In computer vision there exists different ways for finding objects in images:

- image classification will tell you if an image is something (i.e. this image is a cat)
- image detection will tell you where something is in an image (i.e. it will draw a box around a cat)
- image segmentation will try to extract the exact contour of something in an image (i.e. the precise contour of the cat, not just a box containing it)

You need a neural network capable of doing the second or third task with aerial images of trees.

Then simply sum all the tree' areas and compare the result with the image size.

Here you can find a Tensorflow network for doing object detection https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection.